# How to anchor viewForHeaderInSection views of UITableView to top?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, header

I need to implement a table view with multiple sections and by specifying views for the `viewForHeaderInSection`.  I know that the default behavior is that when a section header view is visible and the other section's header comes scrolling from the bottom, then the first one is pushed off the table view and the bottom one is placed on the top.

What I need is anchoring all these header views on top of the tableview, like stacking them under each other. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any data for that particular section. So, it would display only sections in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you are looking for an accordion effect similar to one demonstrated [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

or as in below image

[image]

if this is what expected then u have to

1. create a custom view which expands/shrinks when tapped. add a table view to the same view render sub items in it.
2. Now in your VC return 0 for numberOfRowsinSection and just return custom views to viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: But this does not accumulate the header views as the user scrolls from bottom to top, right? It works by tapping, as far as I could think of.